# Display live user from firebase database on textview in Android studio

Tags: android

I want to show how many live user that are using app from firebase realtime database in Android studio

I am expecting that the every time when user closes or open the app the textview value will change that show the live users that are using app

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.